# How to tell if you've reached the end of a for-loop on an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently trying to build a playlist function which takes a music library and produces a random playlist from it, of a specified minimum duration. The idea is that it takes a minimum rating from a user - but, if there aren't enough tracks of that rating to fill the playlist, it goes for tracks of `minimumRating - 1`. Thus, if you wanted 60 minutes of 5-star tracks, but you don't have enough, the program will try to fill the rest with 4-star ones.

So I need a way of decrementing the `minimumRating` once it reaches the end of its for-loop, then setting it off again. Is there a method I can use which returns something (maybe a boolean) if the for-loop has reached its end?

In case it's helpful, my current code can be found here:

`public ArrayList<Track> createPlaylist(int minRating, int minDuration) {
        minDuration = minDuration * 60;
        ArrayList<Track> shuffledList = trackList;
        ArrayList<Track> playlist = new ArrayList<Track>();
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledList);
        int playlistDuration = 0;
        while (playlistDuration < minDuration) {
            for (Track track : shuffledList) {
                if (track.getRating() >= minRating) {
                    playlist.add(track);
                    playlistDuration += track.getLength();
                }
            }
        }
        return playlist;
    }`

Comment: Why not make a List sorted by stars and end the four loop after 60 minutes? And there is still the for(;;)-loop syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public ArrayList<Track> createPlaylist(final int minRating, int minDuration) {
    minDuration = minDuration * 60;
    final ArrayList<Track> shuffledList = trackList;
    final ArrayList<Track> playlist = new ArrayList<Track>();
    Collections.shuffle(shuffledList);
    int playlistDuration = 0;
    int myMin = minRating;
    while (playlistDuration < minDuration && myMin > 0) {
        for (final Track track : shuffledList) {
            if (track.getRating() >= myMin && !playlist.contains(track)) {
                playlist.add(track);
                playlistDuration += track.getLength();
            }
        }
        myMin--;
    }
    return playlist;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm interested to learn why so many of these values are final though (minRating, shuffledList etc.) I know it stops a new assignment, but why is that beneficial?

Comment: But why not allow minRating to change and remove the `int myMin = minRating;` line?

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you arent going to use the original value of minRating in the method.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came into my mind is that you could make a class for Playlist:

```
public class Playlist {
    private final List<Track> playlist = new ArrayList<Track>();
    private int playlistDuration = 0;

    public void addTrack(Track track) {
        playlist.add(track);
        playlistDuration += track.getLength();
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return playlistDuration;
    }

    public List<Track> getPlaylist() {
        return playlist;
    }

    public void shufflePlaylist() {
        Collections.shuffle(playlist);
    }
}
```

You could spare a lot of lines in your code, your for-loop would look like this:

```
public ArrayList<Track> createPlaylist(int minRating, int minDuration) {
    minDuration = minDuration * 60;
    playlist.shufflePlaylist();

    while (playlist.getDuration() < minDuration) {
        for (Track track : trackList) {
            if (track.getRating() >= minRating) {
                playlist.addTrack(track);
            }
            if (playlist.getDuration() > minDuration) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    return playlist;
}
```

Comment: A nice answer, thank you. Although I'm slightly confused. The `createPlaylist` method belongs to the `Library` class, so how does that method actually create a `Playlist` object?

Comment: I assumed that you defined a Playlist object as a field outside of the method. You could just make a new Playlist object inside of the createPlaylist method

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Track> createPlaylist(int minRating, int minDuration) {
    minDuration = minDuration * 60;
    ArrayList<Track> sortedList = trackList;
    ArrayList<Track> playlist = new ArrayList<Track>(); 
    Collections.sort(sortedList, Collections.reverseOrder()); // implements comparable at rating
    int playlistDuration = 0; 

    for (Track track : sortedList) { 
        playlist.add(track); 
        playlistDuration += track.getLength(); 
        if (playlistDuration > minDuration)
            break;

    } 

    Collections.shuffle(playlist);
    return playlist
}
```